# How can implement this deep learning model in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Check the [source code in replit](https://replit.com/@TestReplAccount/bynn#main.py).

I have 3 classes (A, B, and C).

I have 6 features:

```
train_x = [[ 6.442  6.338  7.027  8.789 10.009 12.566]
           [ 6.338  7.027  5.338 10.009  8.122 11.217]
           [ 7.027  5.338  5.335  8.122  5.537  6.408]
           [ 5.338  5.335  5.659  5.537  5.241  7.043]]
```

These features represent a 5-character string pattern comprising of 3-classes(e.g. AABBC, etc.).

Let, a 5-character string pattern is one-hot encoded as follows:

```
train_z = [[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]    
           [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
           [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]    
           [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

I think, this is a **[Multi-task learning problem](https://youtu.be/-wqM_ODs-8s?list=PLXovS_5EZGh4_ThQVgO2boGf31Dqs5vzm)**.

So, I wrote the following source code:

```
    # there would be 6 inputs for 6 features
inputs_tensor = keras.Input(shape=(FEATURES_COUNT,))

# there would be 2 hidden layers
hidden_layer_1 = keras.layers.Dense(LAYER_1_NEURON_COUNT, activation="relu")
hidden_layer_2 = keras.layers.Dense(LAYER_2_NEURON_COUNT, activation="relu")

# there would be 15 outputs for 15-bits
# each o/p layer will have 1 neurons for binary data
output_layer_1 = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  # 1 neuraons for 1 output
output_layer_2 = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  # -do-
output_layer_3 = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  # -do-
output_layer_4 = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  # -do-
output_layer_5 = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  # -do-
output_layer_6 = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  # -do-
output_layer_7 = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  # 1 neuraons for 1 output
output_layer_8 = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  # -do-
output_layer_9 = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  # -do-
output_layer_10 = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  # -do-
output_layer_11 = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  # -do-
output_layer_12 = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  # -do-
output_layer_13 = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  # -do-
output_layer_14 = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  # -do-
output_layer_15 = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  # -do-

# assembling the layers.
x = hidden_layer_1(inputs_tensor)
x = hidden_layer_2(x)
# configuring the output
output1 = output_layer_1(x)
output2 = output_layer_2(x)
output3 = output_layer_3(x)
output4 = output_layer_4(x)
output5 = output_layer_5(x)
output6 = output_layer_6(x)
output7 = output_layer_7(x)
output8 = output_layer_8(x)
output9 = output_layer_9(x)
output10 = output_layer_10(x)
output11 = output_layer_11(x)
output12 = output_layer_12(x)
output13 = output_layer_13(x)
output14 = output_layer_14(x)
output15 = output_layer_15(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=[inputs_tensor],
                    outputs=[output1, output2, output3, output4, output5,
                             output6, output7, output8, output9, output10,
                             output11, output12, output13, output14, output15],
                    name="functional_model")

model.summary()
print("Inputs count : ", model.inputs)
print("Outputs count : ", len(model.outputs))

opt_function = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-1, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
#
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
               optimizer=opt_function,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
#

print(train_x,"\n",train_z)

model.fit(
    train_x, train_z,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
)
```

**Generates errors:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pc/source/repos/OneHotEncodingLayer__test/ny_nn___k_15_outputs.py", line 117, in <module>
    model.fit(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1098, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 823, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 696, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2855, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3213, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3065, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 986, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 600, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 973, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:748 train_step
        loss = self.compiled_loss(
    C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:204 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:149 __call__
        losses = ag_call(y_true, y_pred)
    C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:253 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:1605 binary_crossentropy
        K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits), axis=-1)
    C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py:4823 binary_crossentropy
        return nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target, logits=output)
    C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\by_nn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_impl.py:173 sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits
        raise ValueError("logits and labels must have the same shape (%s vs %s)" %

    ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((1, 1) vs (1, 15))


Process finished with exit code 1
```

1. Is my implementation correct? If NOT, how can I correct the implementation?
2. How can I resolve the errors?

Comment: from your code it looks like shape of `train_y` is (1, 15), while network outputs (1,3)

Comment: Just use a single output layer with 15 units and sigmoid activation.

Comment: @xdurch0, the error is gone, but it is not converging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears because the model expect a single output layer with 15 units

```
output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(15, activation='sigmoid')
```

Anyhow, this is not the correct way to implement the model, because your current model disregards the fact that all consecutive groups of 3 output values are linked, because the labels are mutually exclusive.
For example if the model predicts an output `[1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1]` composed of 15 values `1`, it is impossible to decide whether to assign class A, B or C to every character.

Your outputs should be 5 layers with softmax activation trained using the categorical cross-entropy losses (one for every output). The labels should be adapted to this form of output splitting the labels `train_z` into a list of 5 `(N, 3)`-shaped matrices.

The code below should work better than your current model.

```
inputs_tensor = keras.Input(shape=(FEATURES_COUNT,))

# there would be 2 hidden layers
hidden_layer_1 = keras.layers.Dense(LAYER_1_NEURON_COUNT, activation="relu")
hidden_layer_2 = keras.layers.Dense(LAYER_2_NEURON_COUNT, activation="relu")

output_layer_char1 = keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
output_layer_char2 = keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
output_layer_char3 = keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
output_layer_char4 = keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
output_layer_char5 = keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')

x = hidden_layer_1(inputs_tensor)
x = hidden_layer_2(x)
# configuring the output
output1 = output_layer_char1(x)
output2 = output_layer_char2(x)
output3 = output_layer_char3(x)
output4 = output_layer_char4(x)
output5 = output_layer_char5(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=[inputs_tensor],
                    outputs=[output1, output2, output3, output4, output5],
                    name="functional_model")

opt_function = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, decay=1e-1, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

model.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy']*5,
              optimizer=opt_function,
              metrics=[['accuracy']]*5)
model.fit(
    train_x, tf.split(train_z, 5, axis=1),
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
)
```

Comment: *For example, if the model predicts an output `[1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1]` composed of 15 values 1, it is impossible to decide whether to assign class A, B or C to every character.* --- does your source code handle this? If NO, how can I implement that?

Comment: Have you checked the source code in of `load_data_k()` in *Repl.it*?

Comment: The code manages the case `[1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1]` using the softmax activation function. The softmax applied to every group of 3 consecutive values imposes that the sum of every group of 3 values is always 1 (and not 3 like in the case with all 1 predicted).

Comment: After looking at your code, I have only replaced `np.split` with `tf.split` because `train_z` is a `tf.Tensor` and not a `np.ndarray`.

Comment: Can you answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68521906/how-can-implement-a-multi-task-deep-learning-in-keras-using-sequential-model), too?

Answer (score 0):

So I took a look at your code and saw that data_input_k contains 5 observations . . . You just don't have enough data. Neural networks are really only going to work if you have large datasets or the effects in your dataset are very obvious (in which case you'd never use a neural network in the first place).

Comment: 5 observations are only for example. actually, I tested my code with 100000 observations. The result was not what I expected.

Comment: Ah, I'll have to modify or delete my answer.  So if I am understanding your question correctly you basically want to classify each observation into 1 of 15 classes based on the 6 features per observation?  If so then this is a typical multi-classification problem, which means you should have a single softmax layer as your output (classifying into 1 of the 15 classes).  It seems like you are trying to execute a multi-class and label model instead, which as I understand it, is not what you are looking for.